# Adding non-model based content to Collection view output in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Is there a proper or best method way to add non-model content to a backbone collection view? For example, say I have a login form, where the username and password fields both represent models in the collection. In order to display these, all I have to do is iterate through the views for each of these models with something that looks like this:

`addAll: function(){
this.collection.forEach(this.addElementToEl, this);
},`

But what is the proper way to add other elements to the DOM like a container div, icon or parent form element that aren't properly stored using models? Should I just append the extra html to the collection View before rendering it? Obviously I could do this server-side with the initial request but I would like to avoid this as much as possible.

Comment: Does the collection view have a template of its own? Why not put it there?

Comment: From the snippet in your question it seems you're using Backbone in a non-standard way. It would be helpful to see more of your code in order to advise better.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a good way. When you need render a non-trival view, there are two things to keep in mind. First, prefer template (e.g. underscore supplies a simple template engine) to manual DOM construction, because template is much more readable and maintainable. Second, prefer hierarchical structure to single-layer structure. For example, don't loop over collections in your templates. Each view is only responsible for rendering its own content, and its children recursively handle theirs. This will make your code simpler and more maintainable. The other benefit of this hierarchical structure is that it leads to finer granularity of view and smaller AJAX-refresh zone. In fact, this is one of the principles of Backbone.

I recommend you read this excellent [article](http://jonathanotto.com/blog/backbone_js_for_the_everyman.html).